# Disk space not decreasing after gc_grace_seconds (10 days) elapsed

Tags: cassandra

I deleted a lot of data(10 billions rows) from my table (made a small app that query from LONG.MIN_VALUE up to LONG.MAX_VALUE in token range and DELETE some data).

**Disk space did not decrease after 20 days from then (also I run nodetool repair on 1 node from total of 6), but number of keys(estimate) have decrease accordingly.**

Will the space decrease in the future in a natural way, or there is some utility from cassandra I need to run to reclaim the space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, yes, the space will decrease accordingly (once compaction runs). Depending on the compaction strategy chosen for that table, it could take some time. Size Tiered Compaction Strategy for example requires, by default, that 4 sstables be the same size before being compacted. If you have very large SSTABLES then they may not get compacted for quite some time, or indefinitely if there are not 4 of the same size. A manual compaction would fix that situation, but it would put everything in a single sstable, which is not recommended either. If the resulting sstable of a manual compaction is very small, then it won't hurt you. If it ends up compacting to a "large" SSTABLE, then you have sacrificed "now" for "later" (again, because you now have only a single large sstable, it may take a very long time for it to participate in compaction). You can split the sstable after a manual compaction to remidy the situation you've created, but you'll have to take your node off-line to do it. Anyway, short answer is that over time the table should shrink accordingly - when depends on the compaction strategy chosen.

Comment: Wartnich Thank you. I decided to just sit and wait and let the "nature" do it's job :). The compaction is the default one, SizeTieredCompactionStrategy.

Answer (score 1):

Try running "nodetool garbagecollect" as this will trigger compaction and removes deleted data. which you can verify running status by "nodetool compacationstats"